# Python JSON keys without parse

Tags: python, json, parsing

I need to get the main keys (devices) from a JSON formatted text with around 70.000 (sub-)keys/objects
It looks like this:

```
{
   "1":{...........}
   "4":{...........}
   "9":{...........}
}
```

And I need to get "1","4" and "9". But the way I do it now it takes around 2 minutes to parse the text with

```
json = json.loads(response.text) #this takes so long!
devices = json.keys()
```

because i'm running this on a Raspberry Pi!

Is there a better way?

**EDIT:**
I recieve the data from a JSON API running on a server with:

```
http://.../ZWaveAPI/Run/devices #this is an array
```

**EDIT3:**

final working code: (runs for 2-5 seconds! :)

```
import ijson.backends.python as ijson
import urllib

parser = ijson.parse(urllib.urlopen("http://.../ZWaveAPI/Run/devices"))
list = []
for prefix,event,value in parser:
    if event == "map_key" and len(prefix) == 0:
        list.append(value)
return list
```

Comment: use a database and only query what you need when you need it?

Comment: I can't change the data I get... I recieve a text with many keys and I need to get the main keys...
Or is there a possibility in the way I get the data? ( see Edit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with an stream-oriented iterative JSON parser, but you'll need to install it separately. Try out [`ijson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/), it'll emit events for each JSON structure encountered:

```
for prefix, event, value in parser:
    if event == 'map_key':
        print value
```

Comment: But this will just call events when it parses, it is not faster, or is it?

Comment: It will give you access to intermediate results faster since you'll get them before the whole thing is loaded.  It will also use a lot less memory since you won't be building up a giant data structure filled with things you aren't going to use.  So it should be at least somewhat faster.

Comment: @TeNNoX: you have to scan over the intermediary results *anyway* to get to the keys you are interested in. But with a streaming parser you don't need to create python objects for the whole data set, which speeds things up.

Comment: Okay then I will try that. But events aren't really necessary because I need to wait for everything to finish anyways, right?

Comment: @TeNNoX: It needs a file-like object; pass in the result of `urlopen()` **without** calling `.read()` yourself.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. Now it outputs every value in the hole file...
I only need the main ones (first level, no subkeys)

Comment: Take a look at the prefix; you should be able to filter on that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there any way by which we can get values only by key, just like a normal dict/json

Comment: @penta: you have to be more specific. A stream handler doesn't give you a dictionary, it gives you `start_map`, `map_key` and `end_map` events, and any of the possible events for values (which themselves can be dictionaries, after all). If you need the value of a specific key, just look for the prefix with the right key, so events with the prefix `foo.bar.baz` define the value for the key `baz` in a dictionary associated with the key `bar`, itself inside `foo`.

Comment: @penta: or use the `ijson.items()` function with a given prefix to get the value or values for a given key.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to experiment with getting just a single device? With most RESTful web services, if you see an URL like this:

> "h ttp://.../ZWaveAPI/Run/devices"

Chances are, you GET individual device by:

> "h ttp://.../ZWaveAPI/Run/devices/1"

If it works, it should greatly reduce the amount of data you have to download and parse.

Comment: Yeah, but I need a valid list of all files. I can't try out all numbers...
By the way I reduced the time now to 3 seconds with ijson as seen in **EDIT3**